# dirname appears not to work with xargs

Tags: osx, xargs, dirname

`xargs` and `basename` work together as I would expect:

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo/index.js bar/index.js baz/index.js | xargs basename
index.js
index.js
index.js
```

`xargs` and `dirname`, though, appear not to work together:

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo/index.js bar/index.js baz/index.js | xargs dirname
usage: dirname path
```

I would expect

```
foo
bar
baz
```

as output. What am I missing?

I'm on Darwin 18.2.0 (macOS 10.14.3).

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: Why using dirname in find command gives dots for each match?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158279/4561887)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dirname` on macOS only takes a single pathname, whereas `basename` is able to work with multiple pathnames.  It is however safest to call `basename` with a single pathname so that it does not accidentally try to remove the the second pathname from the end of the first, as in

```
$ basename some/file e
fil
```

When calling these utilities from `xargs` you may ask `xargs` to run the utility with a single newline-delimited string at a time:

```
printf '%s\n' some arguments | xargs -I {} basename {}
```

or,

```
printf '%s\n' some arguments | xargs -I {} dirname {}
```

You could also use `xargs -L 1 utility` rather than `xargs -I {} utility {}`.

Comment: I fundamentally misunderstood `xargs`. I was under the impression that its default behaviour was to execute the utility once *for each* input line. Thanks for correcting my understanding.

Comment: @davidchambers: If you call `xargs -n1`, you might get the behavior you were expecting. You can compare the output of `ls | xargs echo "TEST"` to `ls | xargs -n1 echo "TEST"` as a test.

Comment: @EricDuminil Note that using `-n` and `-I` divides the input into arguments in _very_ different ways.  With `-n 1`, you'll get one argument per whitespace-delimited word (possibly several such words per line of input), while with `-I {}` you'll get one argument per _line_ of input. Test `xargs -n 1 echo hello` and `xargs -I {} echo hello {}` and give it a single line saying `1 2 3`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Excellent, thanks. `echo "1 2 3\n4 5 6"` is a good test input to see the difference between `-n1` and `-I`

Answer (score 4):

[`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/dirname.html) only takes 1 argument; while the GNU/coreutils version of `dirname` can take more than 1 argument, that is a non-standard extension:

```
SYNOPSIS

    dirname string
```